# function changing property on click (width) not working

Tags: javascript, function, click, width

I started adding some JS to my website and I have problem with this function. It is not working:

html:

```
<img class="button1" src="button1.svg" alt="" onclick="buttonclick()">
```

js:

```
function buttonclick(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("button1").style.setAttribute ("style", "width:500px");
}
```

Comment: If what you pasted in is exactly what you are doing there is a bad space in between `setAttribute` and `("style"...` that might be breaking your code

Answer (score 1):

You could rather try the following, using the button's ID:

```
<img id="button1" src="button1.svg" alt="" onclick="buttonclick()">
```

and:

```
function buttonclick(){
    document.getElementById("button1").css("width", "500px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because read about [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#:~:targetText=The%20getElementsByClassName%20method%20of%20Document,searched%2C%20including%20the%20root%20node..)

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an
>   array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
>   class names.

It means, it is not a single object. So *.style.setAttribute* will not work on your code.

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML, change your image to this:

```
<img class="button1" src="button1.svg" alt="" onclick="buttonclick(this)">
```

and on your JS use this:

```
function buttonclick(element){
   element.style.width = "500px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` method returns an array of elements, therefore to target the first found element you need to target the first item in the array like so:

```js
function buttonclick(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("button1")[0].style.width = "500px";
}
```

```css
img {background:red;height:20px;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<img class="button1" src="button1.svg" alt="x" onclick="buttonclick()">
```

I am guessing you want to change the width of currently clicked "button", so it's best to pass `this` object reference down as a parameter like, so:

```js
function buttonclick(element) {
    element.style.width = "500px";
}
```

```css
img {background:red;height:20px;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<img class="button1" src="button1.svg" alt="x" onclick="buttonclick(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the id it worked for me :

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.width = "500px";

}

Comment: in HTML : <img class="button1"  id="myBtn" src="button1.svg" alt="" onclick="myFunction()">